# How to use a variable to create a variable in Python?

Tags: python, variables, dynamic

I have a list

```
l = [1,2,3,4]
```

and would like to use this to dynamically create empty dataframes to later append data to:

```
for n in l:
    df+str(n) = pd.DataFrame(columns=['col','val'])
```

so you can see the output would be 4 empty dataframe, df1, df2, df3, and df4. But when executed I get a SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression.  How do I go about this?

Comment: It's a bad idea to create variable identifiers based on the value of other variables. Try using a dictionary.

Comment: The proper data structure in this case is a dictionary. Dynamically creating variables is possible using `globals()` but it's an anti-pattern in most programming languages.